# Siri be used to play on Apple TV?

Tags: iphone, appletv, apple-watch, siri

While HomePod can be used to play content on Apple TV, I'm finding a lot of trouble getting my watch or iPhone to play content on Apple TV.

Assuming I can get something to play on Apple TV using the Siri remote, why can't I use the same command from my watch or iPhone?

For example, if I can say to my Siri remote "play Hunters on Amazon" why can't I say to my watch "play Hunters on Amazon on the sitting room apple tv"?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  I _think_ you mean using your phone or watch to _control_ what's playing (which should work with the Remote app on those devices, and does have limited Siri support thru Shortcuts).  If not, then maybe you mean using AirPlay to play from your phone (which should work) or your watch (which does not) to your ATV.

Comment: @jimtut you're right, it's the control. i don't necessarily want to play something from my watch or phone on the apple tv. i want to tell the apple tv what to do from those devices.

Comment: First step is to get the Remote app(s) working on your phone.  Forget about Siri or the watch for now, just get the basic Remote working.  Google how to do that, it's pretty easy, just use the same Apple ID on both devices and "pair" the remote (your phone) with the ATV.  Note that modern iOS has TWO remotes!  There is a full-fledged app, and there is something in the Control Panel.  You can use either, but might as well get both working.  Check back when you do, and we can talk Siri...

Comment: Right. That's working. Are you going to say to use Siri Shortcuts with the remote apps?

Comment: Correct.  That's the only way I can think of to use Siri on a phone/watch to control the ATV.